# Laravel Eloquent query limit and offset is being added automatically to count query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Limit and offset is being added automatically to my following query although I am not adding any limit and offset into it.

```php
$total_trashed_records = $query_records_trashed
                             ->onlyTrashed()
                             ->count();
```

Below are are my queries. Last query is just to return total number of users in trash but `limit` and `offset` are being added and it isn't working.

Below are my queries.

```php
$fields = ["id", "first_name","last_name","username","user_type","job_title","status"];

  $query_records = User::select($fields)
                           ->Where('first_name', 'like', '%' .$s. '%');

   $query_records_trashed = $query_records;    
   $total_records = $query_records->count();

   $records = $query_records
                  ->orderBy($sort_column, $sort_order)
                  ->skip($page*$rows_per_page)
                  >take($rows_per_page)
                  ->get();

  $total_trashed_records = $query_records_trashed
                               ->onlyTrashed()
                               ->count();
```

Below is the result of last query in query log.

```php
"query" => "select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `first_name` like ?  and `users`.`deleted_at` is not null limit 50 offset 0",
"bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "%%"
     ]

"time" => 0.67
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `limit` and `offset` from the produced query, you'd need to remove these two lines from your query builder:

```
->skip($page*$rows_per_page)
->take($rows_per_page)
```

which equate to `offset` and `limit` respectively.

---

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) of the documentation.

Comment: Limit and offsets are added to last query and I am not adding skip() and take() to this query. Basically this is the problem, I am adding skip() and take() to above query and it's automatically being added to last query. $total_trashed_records = $query_records_trashed
                               ->onlyTrashed()
                               ->count();

Comment: ah, ok, I see now. That will be because you are doing `$total_trashed_records = $query_records_trashed....` which already has all those query builder methods chained together, I think you need to split it and not use `$query_records_trashed` there to avoid the issue, there's probably a neat way of doing that.